# ActiveMQ with subscriber JMS selector

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jms-queue

I am trying to port a current RabbitMQ implementation over to ActiveMQ (for several reasons beyond my control). I'm trying to design the same flow of data as our current RabbitMQ design.

In our current design we create a topic in RabbitMQ, then consumers (players) create their queues and bind to the topic using a key binding ( with the format `player-[id]-[up/down]`). So you end up with a Topic named `GamePoints` and thousands of queues (one per player) binding to that topic with the key equals to the player id. We can now produce a message to the `GamePoints` topic with a key of `player-1234-up` and the player with that ID will receive the message. This is working great. This also allows us to create key bindings like `player-1234-*` and receive all the messages destined to that player.

I'm new to ActiveMQ and trying to mimic this behavior. So far I've come up with the following:

- We create a topic named `GamePoints`
- Each player, when it connects, will create a subscriber to the topic with a JMS Selector of `playerId=1234`
- When the game produces a message it sends it to the `GamePoints` topic with the `PlayerId` header value of `1234`
- The subscriber with the JMS Selector (as long as is active at that time) will receive this message, no other subscriber will receive it
- We can also create subscribers with selectors like `playerId like '1234-%'`

Is this a good pattern? I'm afraid of this not scaling because in the scenario where I have hundreds of thousands of subscribers it will have to run the JMS selector hundreds of thousands per message

Thank you for your help!

Comment: After further investigation on ActiveMQ it seems I should be able to acomplish this using Virtual Topics?

Comment: after even more investigation it looks like I can't have more than one consumer on the same queue in a virtual topic in order to deliver the message to more than one listener (as supposed to have all consumers competing for the same message)